# How do I move a TextField above the keyboard while typing | Flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, dart, keyboard, textfield

I want to see what I am typing, but in my code the TextField stays under the keyboard.
I´d be pretty reliefed if any of you guys know a solution to move the TextField above the keyboard!

```
  @override
  _object1State createState() => _object1State();
}

class _object1State extends State<object1> {
  String insert = '';

  void change_insert(new_text){
    setState(() {
      insert  = new_text;
    });
  } 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text(insert),
          TextField(
          onSubmitted: change_insert,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: 'click here ',
          ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

would suggest you to use flutter's new form widget inside that widget you can pass multiple textformfields widgets .

Once you Use these 2 widgets , Flutter will automatically take care of   keyboard and input everttime you start typing.

https://www.github.com/mrinaljain/flutter_shoping_cart/tree/master/lib%2Fscreens%2Fedit_product_screen.dart

Comment: Just so that´s clear: You mean to add a form widget with a textformfield inside. And once I´ve done that, flutter will move the textformfield above the keyboard?

Comment: Yes you can reffer to the form widget I have provided in the URL above.